# Prolog Constants

Tags: prolog

Is there any way to define constants in prolog?

I'd like to write something like

```
list1 :- [1, 2, 3].
list2 :- [4, 5, 6].

predicate(L) :- append(list1, list2, L).
```

The work-around I'm using now is

```
list1([1, 2, 3]).
list2([4, 5, 6]).

predicate(L) :-
    list1(L1),
    list2(L2),
    append(L1, L2, L).
```

but it's a bit clumsy to bind a "useless" variable like this every time I need to access the constant.

Another (even uglier) work around I suppose, would be to include cpp in the build-chain.

(In my actual application, the list is a large LUT used in many places.)

Comment: That's not a work-around. That's called fact-declaration. You declaring fact that `list1/1` is successive goal if its argument is `[1,2,3]`. There is no variables in prolog, so you can assume that every "value" (atom or term) is constant and each "variable" (value name) is non-determinitict constant. Each "variable" (ex. `L1`) can hold even `(1+2*3)` and it will never be interpreted, because that's term (something like `(1+(2*3))` and there is fact `(7 is (1+(2*3)).`). When you pass `list1` as argument of append it is interpreted as atom. You can define `myappend(list1,list2,[1,2,3,4,5,6]).`

Comment: I *use* fact-declaration as a work-around for not having constants.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in 'pure' Prolog (though some implementations may let you do something close, for example ECLiPSe has shelves).

The reason is:

1) You can't write things *like*

```
list1 :- [4, 5, 6].
```

or

```
list1 = [4, 5, 6].
```

Because right hand side and left hand side are both grounds terms which don't match.

2) You can't write things *like*

```
List1 :- [4, 5, 6].
```

or

```
List1 = [4, 5, 6].
```

because the left hand side is now a variable, but variables are only allowed in predicate heads/bodies.

What you *could* do is to define a multi-option predicate like:

```
myList([1, 2, 3]).
myList([4, 5, 6]).
```

and then retrieve all its values with bagof (or similar predicates):

```
predicate(L) :-
    bagof(ML, myList(ML), MLs),        
    concat(MLs, L).
```

`MLs` is the list of all `ML` values that satisfy `myList(ML)` and of course `concat` concatenates a list of lists.

Comment: I agree with your answer, and think that using ground terms like `p([1,2,3]).` or 0-arity terms like `x.` is generally the way to go to define _global_ constants in PROLOG, and to use such terms when local in the definition of predicates, which could include something like `List1 = [4, 5, 6]` as a subgoal (as you mentioned).

Comment: shouldn't there be a comma at the end of bagof ststement? I am not able to get MLs into a single list.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that in Prolog, and defining it via a predicate is the sensible thing to do.

Or better, encapsulate your lookup function in a predicate.

That said, if you really want to use preprocessing there is `term_expansion/2`, but it can make your code unreadable and messy if you are not careful.

You could also look into extensions of Prolog that include function notation (functional logic languages like [Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(programming_language))). But these are even more exotic than Prolog.